# What is the most effective way to speed-up parallel processing with high memory demands using Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am working on a problem involving plenty of similar routines processing and modifying huge (gigabyte scale) shared arrays using recent Python version (3.7+) on a modern multi-CPU local or cloud system. Common speed-up measures like [numpy](https://numpy.org) instead of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) had limited effectiveness or even cause shaky effect ([numba](https://numba.pydata.org/)).

The most effective way so far was to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) with pool.imap call over the carefully preprocessed data. Actually this approach differs from the shared arrays scheme, but any attempts to use manager-based data sharing had resulted in deceleration. Also [ray project](https://github.com/ray-project/ray) had been applied with a negative result possibly due to the huge memory demands.

I there any way to improve both effectiveness and memory usage?

Comment: yes call either Rust or C from within Python to do the work that is intensive.

Comment: Thank you for a prompt reply. Could you please recommend also the details of Rust implementation for the best performance?

Comment: I briefly wrote about it here, inside the Rust you would use something like Rayon for parallelized array work or something similar and then expose that as a function using the CFFI interface to have Python call into Rust checkout : https://williambright.xyz/posts/why-and-how-to-include-rust-inside-python

Comment: Thank you for the amendment. I need to mention that your URL returns Error 526: "Invalid SSL certificate".

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed my certs expired it should be good to go now!

Comment: Thanks, it works now!